# how to store echo of html span id result in php variable?

Tags: php, html

In my code my result is in span id and i want to store my id result by PHP variable.so i want to store the echo statement of php with span tag in php variable and then i want to print that variable.

```
 <?php
     echo '<span id ="cars" ></span>'; 
    ?>
```

i got result like 1234578

but i want to store this result in my PHP variable

i have written

```
<?php
 $test = echo '<span id ="cars" ></span>'; 
?>
```

but i cant able to do this. i got an error.please help me.

Comment: Lose the word echo in the second attempt. And if you need to display it as well, then echo $test after assigning it.

Comment: where did you get this `1234578` result ?, I guess there is javascript included ?

Comment: in $test vairbale i get 123456 but i want $test=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
 //This Statement stores data in variable
 $test = '<span id ="cars" ></span>'; 
 //this is for printing variable that contains data
 echo $test;
?>
```

Comment: what's your question and what you asking for ? Update question

Comment: you give me perfect solution of echo...but now i want result like this...so please help me

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your variable `$test` to be 1234578 value, or your "`<span id="cars"></span>`" tag?

```
<?php

$test = 1234578;
echo "<span id=\"cars\">" . $test . "</span>";    //  ??

?>
```

Or...?

```
<?php

$test = "<span id=\"cars\"></span>";
echo $test; 

?>
```

**EDIT:** To use an array with these numbers, try this:

```
<?php

$test = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8);
echo "<span id=\"cars\">";
foreach ($test as $k => $v)
    echo $test[$k] . ", ";
echo "</span>";

?>
```

There really isn't enough information on this question, and your specifications are very ambiguous and broad.

Comment: I want to print "<span id="cars"></span>" response as array

Comment: what is the $v?

Comment: Technically you can leave out the `=> $v` in my example. [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loops through an array, with any values given. $k is the current index, and $v is the value for that current index. So in my example, **`echo $test[$k] . ", ";`** is the same thing as **`echo $v . ", ";`**